# executing a string containing special characters

Tags: linux, ksh

RH6
ksh93

I'm having trouble getting a kornshell script to execute a command. The following two vars are constant between two commands

```
GLOBAL_CAT=/a/path/to/a/dir
DATA=/a/data/file.txt
```

cmd 1:
    m_cat_add -catalog $GLOBAL_CAT -data $DATA -key '{aKey1}'

cmd 2:
    m_cat_add -catalog $GLOBAL_CAT -data $DATA -key '{aKey1; aKey2}'

pay close attention to the single-quotes enclosing the braces and to the semicolon separating the two key values

both cmd1 and cmd2 work great **when entered interactively from the keyboard**
m_cat command requires that the value for -key be enclosed by single-quotes

Now I whip up a handy kornshell script:

```
GLOBAL_CAT=/a/path/to/a/dir
DATA=/a/data/file.txt
KEYY="{aKey1}"
CMDSTR="m_cat -catalog ${GLOBAL_CAT} -data ${DATA} -key '${KEYY}'"
`eval "$CMDSTR"`      # works 
KEYY="{aKey1; aKey2}"
CMDSTR="m_cat -catalog ${GLOBAL_CAT} -data ${DATA} -key '${KEYY}'"
`eval "$CMDSTR"`      # m_cat throws a "usage" errmsg
```

So there's something subtle and hinky happening with that semicolon being present, its as if ksh is, after expanding the vars, ignores that the single quotes and assumes the semicolon marks the end of the command , which is a failed syntax to the m_cat command.

In the real world, my script reads in the three vars from a file in a while-loop so I can't just hand-edit KEYY

Any ideas? backslashes? forcing a literal somehow?

TIA,

Still-learning Steve

Comment: Could you include `m_cat -catalog ${GLOBAL_CAT} -data ${DATA} -key '${KEYY}'` outputs?    Running  `\`eval "$CMDSTR"\``  mean you execute the `eval "$CMDSTR"` output once again as a command.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out semicolon is one of the default IFS characters and implicit parsing happens during variable expansion. So with

```
KEYY="{aKey1; aKey2}"
```

CMDSTR becomes

```
m_cat -catlog foobar -data bohica '{aKey
```

which can't be a valid command due to the unmatched single-quote. The solution was to set IFS to a character I know won't ever be in the string

```
IFS='<'
```

That did the trick. Thanks to all that replied!

Still-learning Steve